# extract specific texts in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

From the following text file, how the required set of characters can be extracted from each line into a list in python? The required characters are "ONLY REQUIRED1.JPG", "ONLY REQUIRED2.JPG", "ONLY REQUIRED3.JPG". So the result should be:

```
result = ['ONLY REQUIRED1.JPG', 'ONLY REQUIRED2.JPG', 'ONLY REQUIRED3.JPG']


x'<xxx "-//xxx//xxxx//xx">\n<ggg>\n <kkk>\n  <title>asdf asdf/xx/aaa.xxx/bbb.bb.cc</asdf>\n </head>\n <body>\n<pre>\ndhh\n</pre>\n<pre><img src="/icons/blank.gif" alt="Icon "> <a href="?C=N;O=D">Name</a>                                    alt="[DIR]"> <a href="/asdf/kkkk.xxx/">Parent Directory</a>                                                        \n<img src="/lllll/ttt.gif" alt="[IMG]"> \n <a href="ONLY_REQUIRED1.JPG">ertwe</a> \n href="ONLY_REQUIRED2.JPG">x'<xxx "-//xxx//xxxx//xx">\n<ggg>\n <kkk>\n  <title>asdf asdf/xx/aaa.xxx/bbb.bb.cc</asdf>\n </head>\n <body>\n<pre>\ndhh\n</pre>\n<pre><img src="/icons/blank.gif" alt="Icon "> <a href="?C=N;O=D">Name</a> \n href="ONLY_REQUIRED3.JPG">ertwe</a>
```

Comment: `re.findall('ONLY_REQUIRED\d.JPG',my_text)`?

Comment: It is so difficult to understand by new users. Please split the code into two parts. First, let me show how to extract only those lines that contains ".JPG". Then, let me show how to extract the required texts into list.

Comment: @JoranBeasley what does my_text mean?

Comment: the text you loaded from the file that you want to search

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do it like so

```
import re
my_text = open("some.html").read()
my_list = re.findall("ONLY_REQUIRED\d.JPG",my_text)
print my_list
```

this uses regular expressions .  it is looking for anything that starts with "ONLY_REQUIRED" that is followed by a number and then ends with ".JPG"

Comment: @ Joran Beasley thank you, your answer is good for the answer i asked. however, how can i look for all those that ends with ".JPG" when the names are varied and not "ONLY_REQUIRED"?

Comment: I have asked new question for that new purpose